# I want to make pagination using 2 different data source

Tags: php, mysql, database, text, pagination

I want to pagination using 2 different data sources using PHP.

1, Mysql database

2, Text file

start pagination 1 page from MySQL database data and the end to text file data

Example: in start show data from MySQL DB and then when database data ends then show from text file

Example: 1 to 6 pages show data from db and after page 6 data show from text file

here is text file fetch code

Bro here is  text file fetch code

```
function FetchUsernames(){
    $file_contents = file_get_contents('review_files/usernames.txt');
    $usernames  = explode("\n",$file_contents);
    shuffle($usernames);
    return $usernames;
}

function FetchReviewTitles(){
    $file_contents = file_get_contents('review_files/review_titles.txt');
    $titles  = explode("\n",$file_contents);
    shuffle($titles);
    return $titles;
}

function FetchReviews(){
    $file_contents = file_get_contents('review_files/reviews.txt');
    $reviews  = explode("|",$file_contents);
    shuffle($reviews);
    return $reviews;
}

function MergeTXTFilesData(){
  $FetchUsernames = FetchUsernames();
  $FetchReviewTitles = FetchReviewTitles();
  $FetchReviews = FetchReviews();

foreach ($FetchUsernames as $key => $username){
    if (isset($FetchReviewTitles[$key]) && isset($FetchReviews[$key])){
        $Reviews[$key]['username'] = $username;
        $Reviews[$key]['title'] = $FetchReviewTitles[$key];
        $Reviews[$key]['review'] = $FetchReviews[$key];
    }
}

return $Reviews;
```

and we fetched data from mysql and paginated

but now we need to merge pagination

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: I don't know how to do this?

Comment: Nobody will code for you here to give you whole solution. You've already split your task into steps that need to be done, now try to implement them one after another.

Comment: Brother I updated text fetch from text file and also we done fetch data from mysql and pagination with mysql db now the issue is we need to merge both pagination